# Xcode 6 beta 4 Size Classes not good size

Tags: view, ios8, xcode6, size-classes

I want to use the new tech of apple, the Size Classes, but i don't understand why when i select the iphone size, my view have a width of 400p while my iphone have a width of 320p.
Anybody have an idéa ?

Thank

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should watch the WWDC video on developing adaptive apps. Basically, an iphone in portrait has Regular height and compact width size class. This has nothing to do with the real pixel dimension, since Apple might introduce a new phone that's 350pt wide, but still has the same size classes, so your code would work.

Watch the WWDC session video, and use size-classes together with auto-layout to make your apps.